# Issues with SQL Developer and PostgreSQL JDBC driver

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to assist user who suddenly no longer is able to connect to database using PostgreSQL JDBC driver. PostgreSQL connection tab is not clickable. All of her colleagues do not have such issues. I have re-installed SQL developer several times, backed up and deleted SQL config folders from C:\users\username\appdata\roaming, re-added driver, nothing seems to change. I have limited knowledge about SQL as I don't use it and neither is there much information about this as it doesn't seem like a common issue. User uses following software:
JDK 8 -172 64 bit,
SQL Developer 17.2.0,
PostgreSQL JDBC driver 42.2.18. Added screenshot just in case. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: SQL Deverloper JDBC driver issue]

Comment: the screenshot doesn't show any actual problems, it's not clear by that picture or your description what the actual problem is. Advise your user to get 21.2.1 of sqldev - it's 4 years newer than 17.2

Comment: Well, obviously you would need to select the "PostgreSQL" tab to specify the connection parameters, not the Oracle tab.

Comment: We don't have newer version of SQL Developer packaged within our company. As for the issue, the tab is definitely there, but you can't click on it, it's not interactable.

Comment: So ask your company to get newer free software. Also, check for log messages indicating errors

Comment: Fixed it by removing and installing JDK, perhaps environment settings were messed up